# Почему нужно обособить слова "как красота"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, как

Почему надо обособить "как красота" в части предложения "Такое понятие, как красота, раскрывается..."?

Answer (score 1):

> По общему правилу, обороты с союзом «как» выделяются запятыми, если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово «такой».
>
> Он, рыжий человечек, может назвать такие имена, как Малянов Дмитрий Алексеевич, астроном, Губарь Захар Захарович, инженер, и Снеговой Арнольд Павлович, химико-физик. А. и Б. Стругацкие, За миллиард лет до конца света. Быть может, только такие люди, как Шиллер, могли быть достойны ее любви. К. Паустовский, Ручьи, где плещется форель. Отчего же ты не старый, // А такой, как был тогда? А. Ахматова, Веет ветер лебединый... «…Это в общем сон, но не такой, как обычно»... Б. Окуджава, Путешествие дилетантов. Садись такой, как ты есть. Не принаряжайся. Б. Пастернак, Доктор Живаго. Дуб был точно такой, как в царскосельском саду. Ю. Тынянов. Кюхля. Такие, как ты, рождались во все эпохи кровавой истории наших планет. А. и Б. Стругацкие, Трудно быть богом. Теперь, хлопче, скажу тебе, и бабы не такие, как прежде. В. Короленко, Лес шумит.

([Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722))

Comment: Само это правило я тоже видела. Меня интересует, как классифицировать именно этот оборот с "как", чтоб объяснить школьникам. Уточнение? Несогласованное приложение?

Comment: У нас на сайте есть учителя. Пусть лучше они ответят, как это объяснить школьникам.